# What is Isomorphism Types of Abelian Composition Factors?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, definition, intuition

$G$ is transitive group of degree $n$. Now I came to know that if  $G$ has a subnormal/normal chain then $G_i/G_{i+1}$ is a composition factor of that chain, if that quotient group is simple.

Also, "Is isomorphic to" is an equivalence relation. The isomorphism type of a group is its equivalence class with respect to this relation, so that two groups have the same isomorphism type if and only if they are isomorphic.

The following definition is given in [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.08266.pdf):

> $\text{Comp}_A(G)$ -the set of isomorphism types of Abelian composition
> factors of a group G. Note that we have $|\text{Comp}_A(G)| \leq \log |G|$.

According to above understandings, he idea I get that is:

$\text{Comp}_A(G)$ is a set of Simple Quotient Groups $G_i/G_{i+1}$ for all $i$, and all isomorphic groups of $G_i/G_{i+1}$ (for each $i$).

Is this understanding correct? Can anyone give a short example?

Comment: I think you got it exactly the opposite way. Not *all* isomorphic groups, just one. For example, the compositions factors of $C_2\times C_2$ are $C_2$ and $C_2$, but $\mathrm{Comp}_A(G)$ would only contain a single copy of $C_2$. So you take all the abelian composition factors, and then select just one from each isomorphism class among them.

Comment: For $S_4$, the composition factors come from the series $1\triangleleft V\triangleleft A_4\triangleleft S_4$, so the composition factors are $V$ (the Klein $4$-group), $C_3$, and $C_2$, so those three would be in your set. For $S_5$, the composition factors are $A_5$ and $C_2$, so the set would contain just a copy of $C_2$.

Comment: You have to be careful here, because it is perhaps more frequent to regard the (isomorphism types) of composition factors of a group to be a multiset rather than a set, in which case the composition factors of $A_4$ would be $C_2$, $C_2$ and $C_3$, with $C_2$ repeated. But I looked quickly at the paper in question, and the author (Pyber) is definitely considering the set rather than the multiset, so yes, ${\rm Comp}_A(A_4) = \{C_2,C_3\}$ has size $2$.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Oops, of course; $V$ should be further broken up into $C_2$ pieces, just as in the previous comment. Thanks for pointing it out.