# How to show $|\text{Comp}_A(G)| \leq \log |G|$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

$\text{Comp}_A(G)$ is a set of Simple Quotient Groups $G_i/G_{i+1}$ for all $i$ (taking all the abelian composition factors, and then select just one from each isomorphism class among them, ([see the discussion here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4224585/what-is-isomorphism-types-of-abelian-composition-factors)).

Since, $G$ is transitive group of degree $n$, if  $G$ has a subnormal/normal chain then $G_i/G_{i+1}$ is a composition factor of that chain, if that quotient group is simple. Also, "Is isomorphic to" is an equivalence relation. The isomorphism type of a group is its equivalence class with respect to this relation, so that two groups have the same isomorphism type if and only if they are isomorphic.

In [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.08266.pdf) I found that:

> $\text{Comp}_A(G)$ -the set of isomorphism types of Abelian composition
> factors of a group G. Note that we have $|\text{Comp}_A(G)| \leq \log |G|$.

**How to show** $|\text{Comp}_A(G)| \leq \log |G|$?

For any group $G$ of size $n$, there exists a generating set of size $\log n$.
let $x \in G \setminus G_i$ (set-subtraction) and $G =< G_i, x>$. Since $x$ forms at least two distinct cosets of $G_i$, $|G_{i+1}| \geq 2|G_i|$. And hence, in at
most $\log n$ steps we will hit $G$.

Can we use argument to show $|\text{Comp}_A(G)| \leq \log |G|$? How?  If not, what other way to prove the inequality?

[This question may also be related to this unanswered question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4222234/product-of-prime-factors-of-group-order-leq-n-cdot-frac-n-2-log-frac-n)

Comment: Hint: the order of $G$ is greater than or equal to the product of the orders of the (isomorphism types of) composition factors of $G$. Also, by definition, every simple group has order $\geq 2$.

Comment: This is a situation where an apparently more difficult problem is easier, because there are fewer irrelevant distractions. Let $1 = G_0 < G_1 < \cdots < G_n = G$ be a composition series for $G$. Then $n \le \log_2 |G|$, and it follows immediately that the total number of composition factors of $G$, including the nonabelian ones, is at most $\log_2 |G|$.

Comment: @DerekHolt I failed to see the argument, could you please elaborate a little more on how "it follows immediately that the total number ..."? I am from different background.

Comment: I am sorry bit I don't see how I can elaborate on that. That is exactly what the inequality $n \le \log_2 |G|$ says!

Comment: @DerekHolt since there are $n$ groups in the chain, the number of composition factor (or the set of  isomorphism type of compositions factors) has to be $\leq n$, but how do I know   $n \leq \log_2{|G|}$? how do we get the logarithm $ \log_2{|G|}$ ?

Comment: That is not what you asked in your previous comment! Would it help if we wrote that inequality as $|G| \ge 2^n$? (I don't think I can help you any more with this - if you want to make progress with the research paper that you are trying to read, then you really have to start figuring these elementary things out for yourself.)